# Does APIGEE support the MQTT IoT Protocol?

Tags: apigee

Does the APIGEE framework support communications bi-directional with MQTT protocol?

We are looking to manage devices via APIGEE.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this protocol is not supported at this time.  If there is enough demand, it can be considered as a possible enhancement.

Answer (score 0):

From kevinswiber @ [community.apigee.com](https://community.apigee.com/questions/1608/what-protocols-are-supported-by-apigee.html), Feb 24, 2015:

Apigee Edge's programmability model **should allow outbound MQTT connections** using Node.js and a module such as MQTT.js (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt). As far as **inbound connections** go, Apigee Edge **does not support MQTT at this time**.

While MQTT has its place, we believe there is value in using HTTP and other Web-based protocols for the Internet of Things. Apigee has sponsored and contributed to Zetta, an open source Internet of Things platform that helps developers expose devices as Web APIs. Other protocols, such as MQTT, can be used in conjunction with Zetta. If you're interested, you can learn more about Zetta here: http://www.zettajs.org. For Zetta-related questions, you may find the discussion group here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/zetta-discuss.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Apigee Link supports MQTT. But it's not publicity available yet. Custom access has to be requested at apigee.

From dmacdonald  @ [community.apigee.com](https://community.apigee.com/questions/22626/can-edge-edge-micro-now-support-clients-connecting.html), Apr 25, 2016:

> http://apigee.com/about/products/apigee-link.
>   This product will support both MQTT and WebSockets protocols for IoT device traffic. If you have a use case that you believe that Apigee Link can help with through its MQTT protocol support then I recommend that you raise your interest in this product here: https://pages.apigee.com/apigee-link-registration.html